# $\|Re(f)\|_{op}$ = $\|f \|_{op}$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

> Let $X$ be a linear space over $\mathbb{C}$, and $f$ ∈ $BL(X, \mathbb{C})$. Show that Re$(f) \in BL(X, \mathbb{R})$, regarded as a linear space over $\mathbb{R}$. Further, Re$(f)$ determines $f$ as follows: $f(x) = Re(f(x)) − iRe(f(ix))$, $x \in X$. If $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm on $X$, then $\|Re(f)\|_{op}$ = $\|f \|_{op}$.

The first two parts of the problem follow easily. Now, we want to show that $\|Re(f)\|_{op}$ = $\|f \|_{op}$. Define $g(x):= Ref(x)$. Clearly $\|f\|_{op} \ge \|g\|_{op}$. Indeed, $\|f\|_{op} = \sup_{\|x\|=1} |f(x)| \ge \sup_{\|x\|=1} |g(x)| = \| g\|_{op}$. Let $\epsilon >0$, then there exists $x_{\epsilon} \in X$ with $\|x_{\epsilon}\| = 1$ such that $|f(x_{\epsilon})| > \|f\|_{op}-\epsilon$. For an argument $\theta_{\epsilon} \in [0,2\pi)$ depending on the point $x_{\epsilon}$, $e^{i\theta_{\epsilon}}f(x_{\epsilon}) = f\left(e^{i\theta_{\epsilon}} x_{\epsilon} \right)$ is real. Notice that $\|e^{i\theta_{\epsilon}} x_{\epsilon}\| = \| x_{\epsilon}\| = 1$.It follows that $f\left(e^{i\theta_{\epsilon}} x_{\epsilon} \right) = Re\{ f\left(e^{i\theta_{\epsilon}} x_{\epsilon} \right)\} = g(e^{i\theta_{\epsilon}} x_{\epsilon} )$ and $$  \|g\|_{op} \ge |f(x_{\epsilon})| = |f(e^{i\theta_{\epsilon}}x_{\epsilon})| = |g(e^{i\theta_{\epsilon}} x_{\epsilon} )| > \|f\|_{op} - \epsilon. $$
Taking Infimum over $\epsilon$ both sides (I am not sure about this part, as $x_\epsilon$ depend on $\epsilon$), we get $\|g\|_{op} \ge \|f\|_{op}$. Which finishes the proof. Is this correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is fine, but I would change a couple of things:

1. I think is much more clear if you write your last line of inequalities like: $$\|g\|_{\rm op} \ge |g(e^{i\theta_{\epsilon}}x_{\epsilon})| = |f(e^{i\theta_{\epsilon}} x_{\epsilon} )| = |f(x_{\epsilon})| > \|f\|_{\rm op} - \epsilon.$$
2. Instead of saying "Taking infimum over $ϵ$ on both sides" I would say something like:

> Since we have proved that $\|g\|_{\rm op} > \|f\|_{\rm op}-\epsilon$ holds for every $\epsilon>0$, then we can conclude that $\|g\|_{\rm op} \ge \|f\|_{\rm op}$ (otherwise $\|g\|_{\rm op} < \|f\|_{\rm op}$, and so for $\epsilon := \|f\|_{\rm op}-\|g\|_{\rm op}>0$ we have $\|g\|_{\rm op} > \|f\|_{\rm op}-\epsilon = \|g\|_{\rm op}$).